# How to provide a text file location in spark when file is on server

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am Learning spark to implement in my project. I want to run command in spark shell-

```
val rddFromFile = spark.sparkContext.textFile("abc");
```

where abc is file location. My file is on remote server and through that remote server I am opening spark shell, how should I specify file location.
I tried to put a text file in local C drive and provided the location to read that, it also did not worked. I am getting similar error for all the file location.

Error :

```
    scala> val rddFromFile = spark.sparkContext.textFile("C:/Users/eee/Spark test/Testspark.txt")

rddFromFile: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = C:/Users/eee/Spark test/Testspark.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:23

    scala>  rddFromFile.collect().foreach(f=>{
         |     println(f)
         |   })

org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "C"
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3281)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3301)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:268)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:239)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:325)
```

Comment: Move or copy your file to the remote.

Answer (score 0):

Spark is expecting the file to be present in the Hadoop FS, as it looks like that's the default file system set in your app.
To load a file from local FS, you need to put it like

`val rddFromFile = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///C:/Users/eee/Spark test/Testspark.txt")`

That will work when you run Spark in local mode.

If you run Spark in the cluster, then the file would have to be present on all executor nodes.

Comment: I started my command in local mode using **spark-shell --master=local** and used above file location in format as mentioned in above comment but it is giving me error - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 2: C:........"
On searching regarding the error tried to use double forward slash as below but got same error. 
val rddFromFile = spark.sparkContext.textFile("file:///C://Users//eee//SparkTest//Testspark.txt")